# My R script has been turned entirely into blank spaces. Is this recoverable?

Tags: r

If I knew how to reproduce this then I would, but I have never encountered this before. I saved my work using RStudio as I normally would, saving the progress of writing my R script. But when I opened it the next day, the entire script has been blanked. It still has the same file size as before, but nothing appears when I open it in RStudio. It just has a blank line 1.

If I open the script in Notepad++ I can see that the entire file has NUL characters. What has happened here? Is this recoverable?

Comment: To restore parts of it, try `history()`.

Comment: sounds like a encoding error,  try:  File -> reopen with encoding  -> System default